# Datatble interpret javascript data

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using datatble in my project and everything works fine except for one problem.

When one of my data is `<script> alert('hello world')</script>` the alert is shown instead of writing `"<script> alert('hello world')</script>"` in my table, how could I prevent that ? My code looks like :

```
$('.datatable_selector').DataTable({
     "serverSide": true,
     "processing": true,
     "ajax" : {
          "url" : "http://myurl.com"
      },
     "columns" : [
          {"data" : "data1"},
          {"data" : "problemData"}
     ]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/security), you should use a render function:

```
{
    data: 'product',
    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text()
}
```